# 403 error on creating node using REST

Tags: 8

I am trying to create an article node using REST API, but i keep getting 403 error. I have given necessary permission. I am trying it with admin login,

```
curl --include   --request POST   --user admin:admin   --header 'Content-type: application/hal+json'   --header 'X-CSRF-Token: uQ2CRae94_BUhy3q_JvRmlLhSqm0cCuV7tq7_ioIZk8'   http://drupal8_contrib.local/node?_format=json   --data-binary '{"_links":{"type":{"href":"http://drupal8_contirb/rest/type/node/article"}},"title":[{"value":"Example node title"}],"type":[{"target_id":"article"}]}'
```

I have enabled all the REST modules and drupal version is 8.1.

Request Header

`$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => '5add3a97-479d-ee36-7ce4-97a410cc899b',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'x-csrf-token' => 'acsr2_Spef5Ah0_TsYRE8p5GUnt3qWcRKEEwrMxodtw',
  'content-type' => 'application/hal+json',
  'authorization' => 'Basic d2VibWFzdGVyOndlYm1hc3Rlcg=='
));`

Response Header

`Cache-Control →must-revalidate, no-cache, private
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →14
Content-Type →application/json
Content-language →en
Date →Tue, 03 May 2016 09:21:25 GMT
Expires →Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator →Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
X-UA-Compatible →IE=edge`

Comment: Can you include the Authentication method that is enabled (such as HTTP Basic Authentication, OAuth, etc...)? And also include the request and response headers of the request?

Comment: Updated with the Headers from Postman.